# iOS 13 present VC modally doesn't work in landcape mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I am using new iOS 13 modal ViewController presentation. In portrait mode it's works fine as page sheet. I am able to swipe down. But in landscape mode it looks like full screen. Not like page sheet.

I am using code to show as page sheet :

```
let vc = ContactVC()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Why its not working in landscape mode. Any thing I am missing ?

Comment: Because you're not presenting a Controller...Delete UIViewController and add the name of the class of your controller... For example: let vc = ViewController()

Comment: @Fabio. i added as an example here..I updated my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. Thing is, that only **iPhone XS Max and iPhone Plus** models use the new iOS 13 Presentation style  ***when in Landscape mode***.

For reference, see this medium article:
https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e

> Form/page/popover presentations on Landscape iPhone Plus and XS Max devices don’t fill the screen because they are regular width.

That means, their screen is large enough to even present it the new way when in Landscape mode.